# CSS boxes floating

Tags: html, css-float, css

Yes, sorry, I should had posted a picture. It looks like this though:[Link](http://www.regin.dk/boxes.jpg)

I am trying to create two boxes with a box beneath them. To the right I want another box present. And I want it all to be within another box. It all works fine, except I just can't get the last box (under3) to float to the right. Can someone better than I, explain what I am missing? Thanks..

Regin

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="boks1a">
    <div class="mini1">test1
   </div>
    <div class="mini2">test2    
   </div>
    <div class="under1">Testing
   </div> 
</div>
    <div class="under3">test3
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
#boks1a_ydre {
border: 10px red solid;
width: 90%;
}
#boks1a {
border: 4px blue solid;
width: 80%;
}

#boks1a .mini1 {
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
outline: 1px red solid;
}
#boks1a .mini2 {
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
outline: 1px green solid;
}
#boks1a .under1 {
clear: both;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 100%;
outline: 1px blue solid;
}
#boks1a .under3 {
float:right;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 100%;
outline: 1px blue solid;
}
#boks1a_ydre .mini3 {

width: 100px;
height: 200px;
float: right;
outline: 10px black solid;
}
```

Comment: please Draw A Picture that how you want the divisions and post your question again,,!!

Comment: I created a JS fiddle of this problem http://jsfiddle.net/9exfH/

Comment: Hi All, Yes, sorry, I should had posted a picture. It looks like this though:
[link](http://www.regin.dk/boxes.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

See above images. After correction Please see demo jsfiddle.net/XbsXz/

Comment: Hi Pawan, Thanks for the answer. It is almost what I want, but now I have added a link so you can see what I was thinking of creating.
[link](http://www.regin.dk/boxes.jpg)